# Are there some relations among the Hilbert series of $A/(I_1 \cap I_2), A/I_1, A/I_2, A/(I_1+I_2)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A=\mathbb{C}[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$ and $I_1, I_2$ two ideals of $A$.

Are there some relations among the Hilbert series of $A/(I_1 \cap I_2), A/I_1, A/I_2, A/(I_1+I_2)$?

I would like to use the Hilbert series of $A/I_1, A/I_2, A/(I_1+I_2)$ to compute the Hilbert series of $A/(I_1 \cap I_2)$. Thank you very much.

Edit: for example, let $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]$ and $I_1 = (x-y, x-w, y-w)$, $I_2=(x-z, z-w, x-w)$, $I_3=(x-y, z-w)$, $I_4=(x-z, y-w)$. I want to compute the Hilbert Series of $A/(I_1 \cap I_2 \cap I_3 \cap I_4)$. I think that $I_1 \cap I_2 \cap I_3 \cap I_4 = ((x-y)(x-z), (w-y)(w-z))$. By using Maple, we have $Hilb(A/(I_1 \cap I_2 \cap I_3 \cap I_4), t) = \frac{1+2t+t^2}{(1-t)^2}$. We also we have $Hilb(A/I_j, t)=\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}$, $j=1,2,3,4$, $Hilb(A/(I_i+I_j), t)=\frac{1}{1-t}$, $i,j =1,2,3,4$, $i \neq j$. Suppose that we know the Hilbert Series $Hilb(A/I_j, t)$, $Hilb(A/(I_i+I_j), t)$. Can we compute the Hilbert Series $Hilb(A/(I_1 \cap I_2 \cap I_3 \cap I_4), t)$ using $Hilb(A/I_j, t)$, $Hilb(A/(I_i+I_j), t)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: So, you don't know a relation for two ideals, and now asking for four!

Comment: @user26857, thank you very much. Yes, I would like to know two ideals case and four ideals case. Any help about the example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure this clarifies the two ideals question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177446/some-exact-sequence-of-ideals-and-quotients

Comment: Are you sure about the answer $\dfrac{1+2t+t^2}{(1-t)^3}$? What I got is $\dfrac{1+2t+t^2}{(1-t)^2}$.

Comment: @Nirvanacs, yes, you are right. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are $I_1, I_2$ graded ideals?

If I am not wrong, the Hilbert series are additive.

Note that we have the isomorphism
$$(I_1+I_2)/I_2\cong I_1/(I_1\cap I_2).$$

Comment: thank you very much. I edited the post.